# How to parse json object with gson based on dynamic SerializedName in Android

Tags: java, android, json, gson

How can I parse this json objects with Gson this url:
http://apis.skplanetx.com/weather/forecast/3hours?appKey=4ce0462a-3884-30ab-ab13-93efb1bc171f&version=1&lon=127.9259&lat=36.991

```
    "wind": {
      "wdir3hour": "176.00",
      "wspd3hour": "3.10",
      "wdir4hour": "",
      "wspd4hour": "",
      "wdir1hour": "173.00",
      "wspd1hour": "3.60",
      "wdir2hour": "175.00",
      "wspd2hour": "3.40"
    },

    "precipitation": {
      "sinceOntime1hour": "0.00",
      "type1hour": "0",
      "sinceOntime2hour": "0.00",
      "type2hour": "0",
      "sinceOntime3hour": "0.00",
      "type3hour": "0",
      "sinceOntime4hour": "",
      "type4hour": ""
    },
```

How can i write java models for this json objects. I dont want to write varibles 
each filed like this.

```
 class Wind{
 @SerializedName("wdir1hour")
 private String wdir1hour;  
 @SerializedName("wdir2hour")
 private String wdir2hour; 
 @SerializedName("wdir3hour")
 private String wdir3hour; 
 @SerializedName("wdir4hour")
 private String wdir4hour; 
 }
```

Who has better idea for this json objects ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current JSON response accessible via the link you provided seems to have a few design issues or suspicions for them. I'll post the JSON here in order not to let it be lost in the future:

```
{
    "weather": {
        "forecast3hours": [
            {
                "grid": {
                    "city": "충북",
                    "county": "충주시",
                    "village": "목행동",
                    "latitude": "37.0135600000",
                    "longitude": "127.9036500000"
                },
                "lightning1hour": "0",
                "timeRelease": "2017-02-24 16:30:00",
                "wind": {
                    "wspd2hour": "3.10",
                    "wdir1hour": "179.00",
                    "wspd1hour": "4.20",
                    "wdir2hour": "176.00",
                    "wdir3hour": "",
                    "wspd3hour": "",
                    "wdir4hour": "",
                    "wspd4hour": ""
                },
                "precipitation": {
                    "sinceOntime1hour": "0.00",
                    "type1hour": "0",
                    "sinceOntime2hour": "0.00",
                    "type2hour": "0",
                    "sinceOntime3hour": "",
                    "type3hour": "",
                    "sinceOntime4hour": "",
                    "type4hour": ""
                },
                "sky": {
                    "code1hour": "SKY_V01",
                    "name1hour": "맑음",
                    "code2hour": "SKY_V01",
                    "name2hour": "맑음",
                    "code3hour": "",
                    "name3hour": "",
                    "code4hour": "",
                    "name4hour": ""
                },
                "temperature": {
                    "temp1hour": "3.20",
                    "temp2hour": "2.00",
                    "temp3hour": "",
                    "temp4hour": ""
                },
                "humidity": {
                    "rh1hour": "41.00",
                    "rh2hour": "50.00",
                    "rh3hour": "",
                    "rh4hour": ""
                },
                "lightning2hour": "0",
                "lightning3hour": "",
                "lightning4hour": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "common": {
        "alertYn": "N",
        "stormYn": "N"
    },
    "result": {
        "code": 9200,
        "requestUrl": "/weather/forecast/3hours?lon=127.9259&lat=36.991&version=1&appKey=4ce0462a-3884-30ab-ab13-93efb1bc171f",
        "message": "성공"
    }
}
```

From my point of view they are:

- No arrays but artificially indexed object keys (and that's the subject of your question).
- Empty strings for probably `null` values rather than `null`s or just exclusion from the response.
- Almost all values are expressed as string literals even if they seem to be non-strings.
- Probably boolean values seem to be marked with the `Yn` suffix, and define `true` and `false` using `"Y"` and `"N"` respectively.

This is why automatic POJO generators may be not the best way to deal with it because they may do not detect "real" type of a particular JSON string value, and moreover they cannot generate custom deserializers. Not sure why it was designed that way, but you can design your custom mappings to make it a little more programmatically-friendly with more control over them.

```java
final class Response {

    final Weather weather = null;
    final Common common = null;
    final Result result = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Response{")
                .append("weather=").append(weather)
                .append(", common=").append(common)
                .append(", result=").append(result)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Weather {

    final List<Forecast> forecast3hours = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Weather{")
                .append("forecast3hours=").append(forecast3hours)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Forecast {

    final Grid grid;
    final Date timeRelease;
    final List<Integer> lightnings;
    final List<Wind> winds;
    final List<Precipitation> precipitations;
    final List<Sky> skies;
    final List<Float> temperatures;
    final List<Float> humidities;

    Forecast(final Grid grid, final Date timeRelease, final List<Integer> lightnings, final List<Wind> winds, final List<Precipitation> precipitations,
            final List<Sky> skies, final List<Float> temperatures, final List<Float> humidities) {
        this.grid = grid;
        this.timeRelease = timeRelease;
        this.lightnings = lightnings;
        this.winds = winds;
        this.precipitations = precipitations;
        this.skies = skies;
        this.temperatures = temperatures;
        this.humidities = humidities;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Forecast{")
                .append("grid=").append(grid)
                .append(", timeRelease=").append(timeRelease)
                .append(", lightnings=").append(lightnings)
                .append(", winds=").append(winds)
                .append(", precipitations=").append(precipitations)
                .append(", skies=").append(skies)
                .append(", temperatures=").append(temperatures)
                .append(", humidities=").append(humidities)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Grid {

    final String city = null;
    final String county = null;
    final String village = null;
    final double latitude = Double.valueOf(0); // disable inlining the primitive double 0
    final double longitude = Double.valueOf(0); // disable inlining the primitive double 0

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Grid{")
                .append("city='").append(city).append('\'')
                .append(", county='").append(county).append('\'')
                .append(", village='").append(village).append('\'')
                .append(", latitude=").append(latitude)
                .append(", longitude=").append(longitude)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Wind {

    final float speed;
    final float direction;

    Wind(final float speed, final float direction) {
        this.speed = speed;
        this.direction = direction;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Wind{")
                .append("speed=").append(speed)
                .append(", direction=").append(direction)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Precipitation {

    final float sinceOntime;
    final int type;

    Precipitation(final float sinceOntime, final int type) {
        this.sinceOntime = sinceOntime;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Precipitation{")
                .append("sinceOntime='").append(sinceOntime).append('\'')
                .append(", type=").append(type)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Sky {

    final String code;
    final String name;

    Sky(final String code, final String name) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Sky{")
                .append("code='").append(code).append('\'')
                .append(", name='").append(name).append('\'')
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Common {

    @SerializedName("alertYn")
    @JsonAdapter(YnToBooleanJsonDeserializer.class)
    final boolean alert = Boolean.valueOf(false); // disable inlining the primitive boolean false

    @SerializedName("stormYn")
    @JsonAdapter(YnToBooleanJsonDeserializer.class)
    final boolean storm = Boolean.valueOf(false); // disable inlining the primitive boolean false

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Common{")
                .append("alert=").append(alert)
                .append(", storm=").append(storm)
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}

final class Result {

    final int code = Integer.valueOf(0); // disable inlining the primitive int 0
    final String requestUrl = null;
    final String message = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder("Result{")
                .append("code=").append(code)
                .append(", requestUrl='").append(requestUrl).append('\'')
                .append(", message='").append(message).append('\'')
                .append('}').toString();
    }

}
```

Some of these mappings have explicit constructors - such objects must be instantiated manually in custom deserializers. If there is no constructors provided, then Gson can deal with such mapping itself having just enough information on how a particular object should be deserialized.

Since that data should be parsed in a non-standard way, a couple of custom deserializators can be implemented. The following type adapter converts `"Y"` and `"N"` to `true` and `false` respectively.

```java
final class YnToBooleanJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {

    // Gson will instantiate this adapter itself
    private YnToBooleanJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final String rawFlag = jsonElement.getAsString();
        switch ( rawFlag ) {
        case "N":
            return false;
        case "Y":
            return true;
        default:
            throw new JsonParseException("Can't parse: " + rawFlag);
        }
    }

}
```

The next `JsonDeserializer` tries to detect `xxx<N>hour`-like keys with regular expressions and extracting the `<N>` index building the lists required to construct a `Forecast` instance. Note that it can parse "lists" (the ones in the JSON) of arbitrary size.

```java
final class ForecastJsonDeserializer
        implements JsonDeserializer<Forecast> {

    // This deserializer does not hold any state and can be instantiated once per application life-cycle.
    private static final JsonDeserializer<Forecast> forecastJsonDeserializer = new ForecastJsonDeserializer();

    private ForecastJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    static JsonDeserializer<Forecast> getForecastJsonDeserializer() {
        return forecastJsonDeserializer;
    }

    @Override
    public Forecast deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        return new Forecast(
                context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("grid"), Grid.class),
                context.deserialize(jsonObject.get("timeRelease"), Date.class),
                lightningsExtractor.parseList(jsonObject),
                windsExtractor.parseList(jsonObject.get("wind").getAsJsonObject()),
                precipitationsExtractor.parseList(jsonObject.get("precipitation").getAsJsonObject()),
                skiesExtractor.parseList(jsonObject.get("sky").getAsJsonObject()),
                temperaturesExtractor.parseList(jsonObject.get("temperature").getAsJsonObject()),
                humiditiesExtractor.parseList(jsonObject.get("humidity").getAsJsonObject())
        );
    }

    private static final AbstractExtractor<Integer> lightningsExtractor = new AbstractExtractor<Integer>(compile("lightning(\\d)hour")) {
        @Override
        protected Integer parse(final int index, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
            final String rawLightning = jsonObject.get("lightning" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            if ( rawLightning.isEmpty() ) {
                return null;
            }
            return parseInt(rawLightning);
        }
    };

    private static final AbstractExtractor<Wind> windsExtractor = new AbstractExtractor<Wind>(compile("(?:wdir|wspd)(\\d)hour")) {
        @Override
        protected Wind parse(final int index, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
            String rawSpeed = jsonObject.get("wspd" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            String rawDirection = jsonObject.get("wdir" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            if ( rawSpeed.isEmpty() && rawDirection.isEmpty() ) {
                return null;
            }
            return new Wind(parseFloat(rawSpeed), parseFloat(rawDirection));
        }
    };

    private static final AbstractExtractor<Precipitation> precipitationsExtractor = new AbstractExtractor<Precipitation>(compile("(?:sinceOntime|type)(\\d)hour")) {
        @Override
        protected Precipitation parse(final int index, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
            final String rawSinceOntime = jsonObject.get("sinceOntime" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            final String rawType = jsonObject.get("type" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            if ( rawSinceOntime.isEmpty() && rawType.isEmpty() ) {
                return null;
            }
            return new Precipitation(parseFloat(rawSinceOntime), parseInt(rawType));
        }
    };

    private static final AbstractExtractor<Sky> skiesExtractor = new AbstractExtractor<Sky>(compile("(?:code|name)(\\d)hour")) {
        @Override
        protected Sky parse(final int index, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
            final String rawCode = jsonObject.get("code" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            final String rawName = jsonObject.get("name" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            if ( rawCode.isEmpty() && rawName.isEmpty() ) {
                return null;
            }
            return new Sky(rawCode, rawName);
        }
    };

    private static final AbstractExtractor<Float> temperaturesExtractor = new AbstractExtractor<Float>(compile("temp(\\d)hour")) {
        @Override
        protected Float parse(final int index, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
            final String rawTemperature = jsonObject.get("temp" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            if ( rawTemperature.isEmpty() ) {
                return null;
            }
            return parseFloat(rawTemperature);
        }
    };

    private static final AbstractExtractor<Float> humiditiesExtractor = new AbstractExtractor<Float>(compile("rh(\\d)hour")) {
        @Override
        protected Float parse(final int index, final JsonObject jsonObject) {
            final String rawHumidity = jsonObject.get("rh" + index + "hour").getAsString();
            if ( rawHumidity.isEmpty() ) {
                return null;
            }
            return parseFloat(rawHumidity);
        }
    };

    private abstract static class AbstractExtractor<T> {

        private final Pattern pattern;

        private AbstractExtractor(final Pattern pattern) {
            this.pattern = pattern;
        }

        protected abstract T parse(int index, JsonObject jsonObject);

        private List<T> parseList(final JsonObject jsonObject) {
            final List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for ( final Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject.entrySet() ) {
                final String key = e.getKey();
                final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(key);
                // Check if the given regular expression matches the key
                if ( matcher.matches() ) {
                    // If yes, then just extract and parse the index 
                    final int index = parseInt(matcher.group(1));
                    // And check if there is enough room in the result list because the JSON response may contain unordered keys
                    while ( index > list.size() ) {
                        list.add(null);
                    }
                    // As Java lists are 0-based
                    if ( list.get(index - 1) == null ) {
                        // Assuming that null marks an object that's probably not parsed yet
                        list.set(index - 1, parse(index, jsonObject));
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }

    }

}
```

And now it all can be put together:

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
            .registerTypeAdapter(Forecast.class, getForecastJsonDeserializer())
            .create();
    final Response response = gson.fromJson(JSON, Response.class);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

The output:

> Response{weather=Weather{forecast3hours=[Forecast{grid=Grid{city='충북', county='충주시', village='목행동', latitude=37.01356, longitude=127.90365}, timeRelease=Fri Feb 24 16:30:00 EET 2017, lightnings=[0, 0, null, null], winds=[Wind{speed=4.2, direction=179.0}, Wind{speed=3.1, direction=176.0}, null, null], precipitations=[Precipitation{sinceOntime='0.0', type=0}, Precipitation{sinceOntime='0.0', type=0}, null, null], skies=[Sky{code='SKY_V01', name='맑음'}, Sky{code='SKY_V01', name='맑음'}, null, null], temperatures=[3.2, 2.0, null, null], humidities=[41.0, 50.0, null, null]}]}, common=Common{alert=false, storm=false}, result=Result{code=9200, requestUrl='/weather/forecast/3hours?lon=127.9259&lat=36.991&version=1&appKey=4ce0462a-3884-30ab-ab13-93efb1bc171f', message='성공'}}

Comment: @NizomjonHajiev No problem, but one more thing: I've just edited my answer by adding the missing YnToBooleanJsonDeserializer implementation (actual Y/N parsing) I forgot to mention while posting the original answer, and by changing `country` to `county` typo. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I have question again how can i registerType adapter in gson with dagger     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.example.nizomjon.enjoyweather.model.test.Response

Comment: Provides
    Singleton
    Named(PRODUCTION)
    Gson provideGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
    }

    Provides
    Singleton
    Named(SKPLANET)
    Gson provideGsonSk() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                .registerTypeAdapter(Forecast.class, ForecastJsonDeserializer.getForecastJsonDeserializer())
                .create();
    }

Comment: @NizomjonHajiev Sorry, I don't think I can help you out here much because I didn't work with Dagger. But as far as I understand Dagger code, you have to bind the singleton named `SKPLANET` to your deserialization component. Does injection work if you provide one `Gson` only? And does `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class` occur on compile time or runtime?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, Use following web site which create pojo of your json

**http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/**

or their is plugin available **Gson format** for android studio

Comment: it takes a lot of time for example filling to recyclerview. I need a better solution if Wind objects comes with 1-12 hours results i have to change agan.That's way i need dynamic one

Comment: if you are sure it has 12 field most for example ,then you can just use the 12 field pojo to parse every json,the only thing you need to do is Doing null check when access the field @NizomjonHajiev

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Json scheme](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for the `Gson` parsing and it will give you the class like

```
package com.ledge.bean;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;

public class WeatherParsing {

    @SerializedName("alertYn")
    @Expose
    private String alertYn;
    @SerializedName("stormYn")
    @Expose
    private String stormYn;

    public String getAlertYn() {
        return alertYn;
    }

    public void setAlertYn(String alertYn) {
        this.alertYn = alertYn;
    }

    public String getStormYn() {
        return stormYn;
    }

    public void setStormYn(String stormYn) {
        this.stormYn = stormYn;
    }


    public class Example {

        @SerializedName("weather")
        @Expose
        private WeatherParsing weather;
        @SerializedName("common")
        @Expose
        private WeatherParsing common;
        @SerializedName("result")
        @Expose
        private Result result;

        public WeatherParsing getWeather() {
            return weather;
        }

        public void setWeather(WeatherParsing weather) {
            this.weather = weather;
        }

        public WeatherParsing getCommon() {
            return common;
        }

        public void setCommon(WeatherParsing common) {
            this.common = common;
        }

        public Result getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public void setResult(Result result) {
            this.result = result;
        }

    }

    public class Forecast3hour {

        @SerializedName("grid")
        @Expose
        private Grid grid;
        @SerializedName("wind")
        @Expose
        private Wind wind;
        @SerializedName("precipitation")
        @Expose
        private Precipitation precipitation;
        @SerializedName("sky")
        @Expose
        private Sky sky;
        @SerializedName("temperature")
        @Expose
        private Temperature temperature;
        @SerializedName("humidity")
        @Expose
        private Humidity humidity;
        @SerializedName("lightning1hour")
        @Expose
        private String lightning1hour;
        @SerializedName("timeRelease")
        @Expose
        private String timeRelease;
        @SerializedName("lightning2hour")
        @Expose
        private String lightning2hour;
        @SerializedName("lightning3hour")
        @Expose
        private String lightning3hour;
        @SerializedName("lightning4hour")
        @Expose
        private String lightning4hour;

        public Grid getGrid() {
            return grid;
        }

        public void setGrid(Grid grid) {
            this.grid = grid;
        }

        public Wind getWind() {
            return wind;
        }

        public void setWind(Wind wind) {
            this.wind = wind;
        }

        public Precipitation getPrecipitation() {
            return precipitation;
        }

        public void setPrecipitation(Precipitation precipitation) {
            this.precipitation = precipitation;
        }

        public Sky getSky() {
            return sky;
        }

        public void setSky(Sky sky) {
            this.sky = sky;
        }

        public Temperature getTemperature() {
            return temperature;
        }

        public void setTemperature(Temperature temperature) {
            this.temperature = temperature;
        }

        public Humidity getHumidity() {
            return humidity;
        }

        public void setHumidity(Humidity humidity) {
            this.humidity = humidity;
        }

        public String getLightning1hour() {
            return lightning1hour;
        }

        public void setLightning1hour(String lightning1hour) {
            this.lightning1hour = lightning1hour;
        }

        public String getTimeRelease() {
            return timeRelease;
        }

        public void setTimeRelease(String timeRelease) {
            this.timeRelease = timeRelease;
        }

        public String getLightning2hour() {
            return lightning2hour;
        }

        public void setLightning2hour(String lightning2hour) {
            this.lightning2hour = lightning2hour;
        }

        public String getLightning3hour() {
            return lightning3hour;
        }

        public void setLightning3hour(String lightning3hour) {
            this.lightning3hour = lightning3hour;
        }

        public String getLightning4hour() {
            return lightning4hour;
        }

        public void setLightning4hour(String lightning4hour) {
            this.lightning4hour = lightning4hour;
        }

    }

    public class Grid {

        @SerializedName("latitude")
        @Expose
        private String latitude;
        @SerializedName("longitude")
        @Expose
        private String longitude;
        @SerializedName("city")
        @Expose
        private String city;
        @SerializedName("county")
        @Expose
        private String county;
        @SerializedName("village")
        @Expose
        private String village;

        public String getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public String getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city = city;
        }

        public String getCounty() {
            return county;
        }

        public void setCounty(String county) {
            this.county = county;
        }

        public String getVillage() {
            return village;
        }

        public void setVillage(String village) {
            this.village = village;
        }

    }

    public class Humidity {

        @SerializedName("rh1hour")
        @Expose
        private String rh1hour;
        @SerializedName("rh2hour")
        @Expose
        private String rh2hour;
        @SerializedName("rh3hour")
        @Expose
        private String rh3hour;
        @SerializedName("rh4hour")
        @Expose
        private String rh4hour;

        public String getRh1hour() {
            return rh1hour;
        }

        public void setRh1hour(String rh1hour) {
            this.rh1hour = rh1hour;
        }

        public String getRh2hour() {
            return rh2hour;
        }

        public void setRh2hour(String rh2hour) {
            this.rh2hour = rh2hour;
        }

        public String getRh3hour() {
            return rh3hour;
        }

        public void setRh3hour(String rh3hour) {
            this.rh3hour = rh3hour;
        }

        public String getRh4hour() {
            return rh4hour;
        }

        public void setRh4hour(String rh4hour) {
            this.rh4hour = rh4hour;
        }
    }

    public class Precipitation {

        @SerializedName("sinceOntime1hour")
        @Expose
        private String sinceOntime1hour;
        @SerializedName("type1hour")
        @Expose
        private String type1hour;
        @SerializedName("sinceOntime2hour")
        @Expose
        private String sinceOntime2hour;
        @SerializedName("type2hour")
        @Expose
        private String type2hour;
        @SerializedName("sinceOntime3hour")
        @Expose
        private String sinceOntime3hour;
        @SerializedName("type3hour")
        @Expose
        private String type3hour;
        @SerializedName("sinceOntime4hour")
        @Expose
        private String sinceOntime4hour;
        @SerializedName("type4hour")
        @Expose
        private String type4hour;

        public String getSinceOntime1hour() {
            return sinceOntime1hour;
        }

        public void setSinceOntime1hour(String sinceOntime1hour) {
            this.sinceOntime1hour = sinceOntime1hour;
        }

        public String getType1hour() {
            return type1hour;
        }

        public void setType1hour(String type1hour) {
            this.type1hour = type1hour;
        }

        public String getSinceOntime2hour() {
            return sinceOntime2hour;
        }

        public void setSinceOntime2hour(String sinceOntime2hour) {
            this.sinceOntime2hour = sinceOntime2hour;
        }

        public String getType2hour() {
            return type2hour;
        }

        public void setType2hour(String type2hour) {
            this.type2hour = type2hour;
        }

        public String getSinceOntime3hour() {
            return sinceOntime3hour;
        }

        public void setSinceOntime3hour(String sinceOntime3hour) {
            this.sinceOntime3hour = sinceOntime3hour;
        }

        public String getType3hour() {
            return type3hour;
        }

        public void setType3hour(String type3hour) {
            this.type3hour = type3hour;
        }

        public String getSinceOntime4hour() {
            return sinceOntime4hour;
        }

        public void setSinceOntime4hour(String sinceOntime4hour) {
            this.sinceOntime4hour = sinceOntime4hour;
        }

        public String getType4hour() {
            return type4hour;
        }

        public void setType4hour(String type4hour) {
            this.type4hour = type4hour;
        }

    }

    public class Result {

        @SerializedName("code")
        @Expose
        private Integer code;
        @SerializedName("requestUrl")
        @Expose
        private String requestUrl;
        @SerializedName("message")
        @Expose
        private String message;

        public Integer getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(Integer code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getRequestUrl() {
            return requestUrl;
        }

        public void setRequestUrl(String requestUrl) {
            this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

    }

    public class Sky {

        @SerializedName("code1hour")
        @Expose
        private String code1hour;
        @SerializedName("name1hour")
        @Expose
        private String name1hour;
        @SerializedName("code2hour")
        @Expose
        private String code2hour;
        @SerializedName("name2hour")
        @Expose
        private String name2hour;
        @SerializedName("code3hour")
        @Expose
        private String code3hour;
        @SerializedName("name3hour")
        @Expose
        private String name3hour;
        @SerializedName("code4hour")
        @Expose
        private String code4hour;
        @SerializedName("name4hour")
        @Expose
        private String name4hour;

        public String getCode1hour() {
            return code1hour;
        }

        public void setCode1hour(String code1hour) {
            this.code1hour = code1hour;
        }

        public String getName1hour() {
            return name1hour;
        }

        public void setName1hour(String name1hour) {
            this.name1hour = name1hour;
        }

        public String getCode2hour() {
            return code2hour;
        }

        public void setCode2hour(String code2hour) {
            this.code2hour = code2hour;
        }

        public String getName2hour() {
            return name2hour;
        }

        public void setName2hour(String name2hour) {
            this.name2hour = name2hour;
        }

        public String getCode3hour() {
            return code3hour;
        }

        public void setCode3hour(String code3hour) {
            this.code3hour = code3hour;
        }

        public String getName3hour() {
            return name3hour;
        }

        public void setName3hour(String name3hour) {
            this.name3hour = name3hour;
        }

        public String getCode4hour() {
            return code4hour;
        }

        public void setCode4hour(String code4hour) {
            this.code4hour = code4hour;
        }

        public String getName4hour() {
            return name4hour;
        }

        public void setName4hour(String name4hour) {
            this.name4hour = name4hour;
        }

    }

    public class Temperature {

        @SerializedName("temp1hour")
        @Expose
        private String temp1hour;
        @SerializedName("temp2hour")
        @Expose
        private String temp2hour;
        @SerializedName("temp3hour")
        @Expose
        private String temp3hour;
        @SerializedName("temp4hour")
        @Expose
        private String temp4hour;

        public String getTemp1hour() {
            return temp1hour;
        }

        public void setTemp1hour(String temp1hour) {
            this.temp1hour = temp1hour;
        }

        public String getTemp2hour() {
            return temp2hour;
        }

        public void setTemp2hour(String temp2hour) {
            this.temp2hour = temp2hour;
        }

        public String getTemp3hour() {
            return temp3hour;
        }

        public void setTemp3hour(String temp3hour) {
            this.temp3hour = temp3hour;
        }

        public String getTemp4hour() {
            return temp4hour;
        }

        public void setTemp4hour(String temp4hour) {
            this.temp4hour = temp4hour;
        }

    }

    public class Weather {

        @SerializedName("forecast3hours")
        @Expose
        private List<Forecast3hour> forecast3hours = null;

        public List<Forecast3hour> getForecast3hours() {
            return forecast3hours;
        }

        public void setForecast3hours(List<Forecast3hour> forecast3hours) {
            this.forecast3hours = forecast3hours;
        }

    }

    public class Wind {

        @SerializedName("wdir3hour")
        @Expose
        private String wdir3hour;
        @SerializedName("wspd3hour")
        @Expose
        private String wspd3hour;
        @SerializedName("wdir4hour")
        @Expose
        private String wdir4hour;
        @SerializedName("wspd4hour")
        @Expose
        private String wspd4hour;
        @SerializedName("wdir1hour")
        @Expose
        private String wdir1hour;
        @SerializedName("wspd1hour")
        @Expose
        private String wspd1hour;
        @SerializedName("wdir2hour")
        @Expose
        private String wdir2hour;
        @SerializedName("wspd2hour")
        @Expose
        private String wspd2hour;

        public String getWdir3hour() {
            return wdir3hour;
        }

        public void setWdir3hour(String wdir3hour) {
            this.wdir3hour = wdir3hour;
        }

        public String getWspd3hour() {
            return wspd3hour;
        }

        public void setWspd3hour(String wspd3hour) {
            this.wspd3hour = wspd3hour;
        }

        public String getWdir4hour() {
            return wdir4hour;
        }

        public void setWdir4hour(String wdir4hour) {
            this.wdir4hour = wdir4hour;
        }

        public String getWspd4hour() {
            return wspd4hour;
        }

        public void setWspd4hour(String wspd4hour) {
            this.wspd4hour = wspd4hour;
        }

        public String getWdir1hour() {
            return wdir1hour;
        }

        public void setWdir1hour(String wdir1hour) {
            this.wdir1hour = wdir1hour;
        }

        public String getWspd1hour() {
            return wspd1hour;
        }

        public void setWspd1hour(String wspd1hour) {
            this.wspd1hour = wspd1hour;
        }

        public String getWdir2hour() {
            return wdir2hour;
        }

        public void setWdir2hour(String wdir2hour) {
            this.wdir2hour = wdir2hour;
        }

        public String getWspd2hour() {
            return wspd2hour;
        }

        public void setWspd2hour(String wspd2hour) {
            this.wspd2hour = wspd2hour;
        }

    }
}
```

And in the code you can get the response are as follow:-

```
   WeatherParsing.Example getData = new Gson().fromJson(response,WeatherParsing.Example.class);
                getData.getWeather().getForecast3hours().get(0).getLightning1hour();
                getData.getCommon();
                getData.getResult();
```