# How to define object type at run time in android model class

Tags: android, model

I have a class:

```
public class Payload{
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private Object data;

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

at run time data can be of any type(custom object). how can i define this?

Comment: Use this link for it :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42438222/3946958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public class Payload<T> {
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    private T data;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and

```
Payload<String> strPayload = new Payload<>();
strPauload.setData("this is the data");

Payload<Integer> intPayload = new Payload<>();
intPauload.setData(635);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Glad to help you!